# The identifier of the max of the variables according to the groups

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have a data frame containing the groups (Gp) and the values (y) of the variables.

My data

```
y <- c(5 , 0.22 , 0.23 , 0.17 , 0.36 , 3.33 , 5.30 , 0.39 , 0.35 ,
0.27 , 0.20 , 0.22 , 0.24 , 0.16 , 0.36 , 0.30 , 0.31 , 0.39 , 0.33 , 0.25 , 0.23 , 0.13 , 0.16 , 6.18 ,  0.20 ,1, 9.15 , 0.09 , 0.18 , 8 , 9 , 0.14 , 3 , 0.18 , 0.22 , 0.16 , 0.14 , 0.11 , 0.18 , 4 , 0.30 ,
0.36 , 0.40 , 0.42 , 8 , 0.23 , 0.25 , 0.30 ,  0.27 , 0.15 , 0.29 , 0.36 , 0.38 , 0.42 , 0.28 , 0.23 , 0.26 , 0.29 , 0.24 , 0.17 , 0.24 , 0.14 , 0.17 , 0.16 , 0.15 , 6 , 0.19 , 0.15 , 0.16 , 0.3) 

Gp <- c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,
           2,2,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3) 

tab <- data.frame(x=as.factor(Gp), y)

tab

   x    y

1  1 5.00

2  2 0.22

3  2 0.23

4  1 0.17

5  2 0.36
```

I would like to have the identifier of the max of the variables according to the groups. I tried:

```
with(tab,tapply(y,x,max))
```

> 1    2    3
>
> 8.00 9.00 9.15

Expected result :

> 30     31      27
>
> 1      2       3
>
> 8.00   9.00    9.15

with ***30  ,   31 , and    27*** are the identifiant of the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea with `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

tab %>% 
 mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
 group_by(x) %>%  
 filter(y == max(y))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
> # Groups:   x [3]
>   x         y index
>   <fct> <dbl> <int>
> 1 3      9.15    27
> 2 1      8.00    30
> 3 2      9.00    31
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using base R functions.

```
sapply(sort(unique(Gp)), function(i) {
               ind <- which(Gp == i)
               ind[which.max(y[ind])]
})

# [1] 30 31 27
```

Following prints the Gp to use as well if it is required. (sort function is optional with this)

```
sapply(sort(unique(Gp)), function(i) {
                ind <- which(Gp == i)  
                c(Gp = i, max_pos = ind[which.max(y[ind])])
})

#         [,1] [,2] [,3]
# Gp         1    2    3
# max_pos   30   31   27
```